# Why Appletviewer throws AccessControlException: access denied

Tags: java, applet, appletviewer

Why Appletviewer throws error with this:

thread = new Thread(this,"main thread");

Comment: whats the error stacktrace in brackets after the 'access denied'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you Thread is trying to do one of these in your Thread:

- Read files on the client file system.
- Write files to the client file
  system.
- Delete files on the client file
  system, either by using the
  File.delete() method, or by calling
  system-level rm or del commands.
- Rename files on the client file
  system, either by using the
  File.renameTo() method, or by calling
  system-level mv or rename commands.
- Create a directory on the client file
  system, either by using the
  File.mkdirs() methods or by calling
  the system-level mkdir command.
- List the contents of a directory.
- Check to see whether a file exists.
- Obtain information about a file,
  including size, type, and
  modification timestamp.
- Create a network connection to any
  computer other than the host from
  which it originated.
- Listen for or accept network
  connections on any port on the client
  system.
- Create a top-level window without an
  untrusted window banner.
- Obtain the user's username or home
  directory name through any means,
  including trying to read the system
  properties: user.name, user.home,
  user.dir, java.home, and
  java.class.path.
- Define any system properties.
- Run any program on the client system
  using the Runtime.exec() methods.
- Make the Java interpreter exit, using
  either System.exit() or
  Runtime.exit().
- Load dynamic libraries on the client
  system using the load() or
  loadLibrary() methods of the Runtime
  or System classes.
- Create or manipulate any thread that
  is not part of the same ThreadGroup
  as the applet.
- Create a ClassLoader.
- Create a SecurityManager.
- Specify any network control
  functions, including
  ContentHandlerFactory,
  SocketImplFactory, or
  URLStreamHandlerFactory.
- Define classes that are part of
  packages on the client system.

You have two solutions

1. Digitally sign your applet
2. Change the security permissions in
   your JRE

[See this for security and applets](http://www.securingjava.com/chapter-two/)